# Have a rails form automatically include month, year and state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does rails have a way to make form field include, all states, all months, and all years within 100 years.

Currently I do stuff like this but doing this will get crazy when I get to states

```
= f.select :birth_month, [['month', nil], 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Comment: this might help - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html. e.g. `select_year(2013, start_year: 1913, end_year: 2013)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a gem that can help you: [the countries gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) which  integrates with [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select), so you have a complete solution for states input.

For date select you can use [date_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) method, passing the parameters `:start_year` and `:end_year`